# Resolution not fitting to screen on second monitor on a Mac mini

Tags: mac, windows-8, resolution, hdmi, mac-mini

I have a Mac mini running Windows 8 these days, but it is the same issue on OS X regardless.

There are a variety of ports on the back of the mini, and currently I'm using a thunderbolt connection that uses a converter to VGA. I have the exact same two TV's, Samsung SyncMaster TA550. The VGA resolution for my first screen is perfect, crisp. But the second monitor uses a HDMI cable as there is only one Thunderbolt port. But this display doesn't fit the screen and is also a little blurry.

Both according to Windows 8 are displaying the exact same resolution but different results.

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: what is the resolution set as on the mac mini?

Comment: @logman 1920x1200

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbolt can support 2560x1600, Mac mini HDMI can only go up to 1920x1200.

The TV is scaling it down and distorting the aspect at the same time.

Fix:

- You need to turn off the auto scaling on the TV source with HDMI. (Doubtful)
- Or lower the Mac mini resolution to 1920x1200. (Probable)
- Or [daisy chain the display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9087/40457). (Maybe)

Comment: Both are running at 1920x1200, I'll try daisy chain though as I don't think it's the scaling of the tv.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to dial down `Underscan` in the display preferences